# How do I apply an array values to Mongodb find() in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

I want to retrieve the specific data using an array-values, but I don't know how to deal with it.

URL is like `http://localhost/api/data?sym=aa&bb&cc`

DB documents are like:

```
{"symbol":"aa","price":1.1}
{"symbol":"bb","price":1.2}
{"symbol":"cc","price":1.3}
{"symbol":"dd","price":1.4}
{"symbol":"ee","price":1.5}
```

the expected result is:

```
[   
{"symbol":"aa","price":1.1}
{"symbol":"bb","price":1.2}
{"symbol":"cc","price":1.3}
]
```

My code is:

```
    [HttpGet()]
    public IEnumerable<Data> Get(string sym)
    {
        symbol = sym.Split('&');

        //connect to database and collections
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://.....");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("...");
        var _portf = db.GetCollection<Data>("...");
        return _portf.Find(???).ToList();
    }
```

**???** is where I have failed to find a solution. or I am completely wrong with the find() method.
I really need your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find` takes in a `FilterDefinition` object. For example, a common way of getting a document from MongoDB by its ID would be:

```
public T LoadRecordById<T>(string table, Guid id)
{
    var collection = db.GetCollection<T>(table);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);

    return collection.Find(filter).First();
}
```

You can combine multiple `FilterDefinition` objects together using the `Or` method:

```
    var filter1 = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("symbol", symbol);
    var filter2 = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("symbol", symbol);
    var filter3 = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("symbol", symbol);

    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Or(filter1, filter2, filter3);
```

Hope this helps (it does not hurt to be nice, does it, @Dharman?)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very promising way which works perfectly. Thanks to [this video](https://youtu.be/EQFRVUrHIjA?t=443)

rewrite the code"

```
[HttpGet()]
    public IEnumerable<Data> Get(string sym)
    {
        var symlist = sym.Split('&');

        //connect to database and collections
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://.....");
        var db = client.GetDatabase("...");
        var _portf = db.GetCollection<Data>("...");

     -->var fitlerDefinition = Builders<Findata>.Filter.In(a => a.Symbol, symlist);

        return _portf.Find(fitlerDefinition).ToList();
    }
```